# Syntax error for where() active record query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to perform the following active record query, but keep getting a syntax error.

`@kid.toys.where("name ILIKE ? OR description ILIKE ?", params[:query], params[:query])`

I am trying to find all toys were the `name` is like `params[:query]` or the `description` is like `params[:query]`

The syntax error I get is the following:

`` {"error":"Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ILIKE '\\\"robot\\\"' OR `description` ILIKE '\\\"robot\\\"')' at line 1: SELECT `items`.* FROM `items` WHERE `items`.`kid_id` = 2 AND (`name` ILIKE '\\\"robot\\\"' OR `description` ILIKE '\\\"robot\\\"')"} ``

Any help or guidance is much appreciated. I will continue to dig around for answers.

Answer (score 4):

`ILIKE` is not an operator in MySQL.  Did you simply mean to use [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)?

```
@kid.toys.where("name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", params[:query], params[:query])
```

If you were instead looking to force the pattern matching to be case-insensitive, you could explicitly use a [case-insensitive collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/case-sensitivity.html) by adding a `COLLATE` clause to either operand of each `LIKE` operation.  For example:

```
@kid.toys.where("name LIKE ? COLLATE utf8_general_ci OR description LIKE ? COLLATE utf8_general_ci", params[:query], params[:query])
```

Comment: i will look into this. without the COLLATE it's not doing what I want, maybe that will make it work

Comment: I am not expecting an empty array back, but that's what is being returned :( the `COLLATE` did not fix it...